# Python Error: Unable to seek to the next packet

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv, pycharm

Working in my first python opencv project,

### Python code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("eye_recording_video.flv")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret is False:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Error while Running

> [flv @ 0x7ff38cafba00] Unable to seek to the next packet

### Project Files

[image]

**How to resolve this issue?**